# Magento 2 : How can I test save and delete model?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, unit-tests, phpunit

I have the problem with writing unit tests. It's my first attempt and I don't know how can I test a couple of cases in my code.

It's action in my controller:

```
    public function execute()
    {
            $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $redirect = $this->_redirect('*/*');
            if ($params) {
                $redirect->setMetadata('params', true);
                try {
                    $customerId = $this->_customerHelper->getCustomer()->getId();
                    $this->_reportModel->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
                        ->addFieldToFilter('type', Entity::CUSTOMER_PREASEASON)
                        ->getFirstItem()
                        ->delete();

                    $this->_reportModel->setData([
                        'customer_id' => $customerId,
                        'type' => Entity::CUSTOMER_PREASEASON,
                        'extra_data' => serialize([
                            'year' => $params['year'],
                            'season' => $params['season']
                        ]),
                    ])->save();
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('You request will be processed');
                    return $redirect;
                } catch (Exception $exception) {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage('Some occurred error');
                }
            }
            $redirect->setMetadata('params', false);
            return $redirect;
}
```

I have to test such cases:

```
   $this->_reportModel->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
                        ->addFieldToFilter('type', Entity::CUSTOMER_PREASEASON)
                        ->getFirstItem()
                        ->delete();
```

And

```
$this->_reportModel->setData([
                    'customer_id' => $customerId,
                    'type' => Entity::CUSTOMER_PREASEASON,
                    'extra_data' => serialize([
                        'year' => $params['year'],
                        'season' => $params['season']
                    ]),
                ])->save();
```

How can I do this? should I initialize `$this->_reportModel` as real model and save it?  Or create Mock (`$this->_reportModelMock`) and set condition for it and do like:

```
$this->_reportCollectionMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getFirstItem')
            ->willReturn($this->_reportModelMock);
```

Maybe I'm wrong and it's not the right way. I will be very grateful if you help me ))) also I will  grateful for an example similar to my problem